# as3 XML value into an array. Can't make it work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm a noob with as3 and I'm trying to learn.

This is something that I cannot understand. I have a very simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SLIDES>
    <IMAGE>01.jpg</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>02.jpg</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>03.jpg</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>04.jpg</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>05.jpg</IMAGE>
</SLIDES>
```

That I'm parsing like this:

```
private function loadXML(filename:String):void {
            var myXML:XML;
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest(filename+".xml"));
            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

            function processXML(e:Event):void {
                myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
                myXML.ignoreWhite=true;

                for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.IMAGE.length(); i++) {
                    imagesURLs.push(myXML.IMAGE[i]);
                    trace(myXML.IMAGE[i]);
                }
            }
            for each (var imageURL:String in imagesURLs) {
                trace(imageURL);
            }
        }
```

The first trace returns:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg
```

While the second is empty! Why? I'm really starting to lose my mind. I also tried:

```
myXML.IMAGE[i].toXMLString()
```

With no luck. Can you please help me and make me undestand why does this happens?

Thank you.

p.s.

The function gets called with the filename I need to parse and the array is declared like so:

```
public var imagesURLs:Array = [];
```

I'm using the latest version of FLEX with flashDevelop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop is executed before the 'processXML' function. At this time your Array is empty !
Your 'processXML' function will be called only when data will be available (asynchronous call)
Also, don't forget to remove your event listener.